# Как сбросить кеш для тэга latest в docker реестре?

Tags: docker

Такая ситуация после пуша в приватный докер реестр образа
например

```
docker push mymage:latest
```

Он успешно туда загружается, но вот получение рандомное.

```
docker pull mymage:latest
```

может вернуть любой более старый образ, иногда новый.

Если использовать другие новые тэги например mymage:latest2 в следующий раз, mymage:latest3 и.т.д то все ок, сразу скачивается корректный образ.

Как лучше сделать, сбросить кеш или удалить или что то еще перед командой push, чтобы гарантированно по тэгу latest получить именно тот, что был загружен последним?

Comment: Предполагаю, что всё-таки с докером всё в порядке. Скорее всего, кто-то делает `docker push myimage` с каким-то старым кодом - в этом случае как раз обновляется `:latest`. И с этого момента выглядит, как будто возвращается старый. Потом кто-то сделает `push myimage:latest` с новым кодом и он опять работает нормально.

Comment: Ещё, кстати, даже вот такая команда `docker build -t myimage` обновит в локальном репозитории тэг `latest`

Comment: Не, там полгода все работало корректно, то есть скрипты которые пушат и получают образы не менялись. Команды те же. Эту ошибку признают специалисты которые обслуживают докер реестр, но предлагают указывать каждый раз новый тэг. Сборку образа выполняет docker-compose

Comment: (1) "всё работало" ну, а сейчас кто-то эксперементирует с докером, и даже не понимает, что он это делает с тэгом `latest` (2) "докер реестр" если это какой-нибудь альтернативный софт так чудит, типа `JFrog` / `Nexus` / `Quay`, то это не проблема докера и средствами докера не решается :)

Comment: Ну там Nexus, эта проблема уже год есть, но не решается. То есть образ latest все таки заливается, но может залиться сразу, а может через 3 дня. А со стороны разработчика что то можно сделать с этим? Никак нельзя удалить полностью весь тэг latest например?

Comment: Я не слышал про такую команду. Даже если бы была - скорее всего работало бы так же, как сейчас. Проблема выглядит как будто свой реестр какой-нибудь распределённый и узлы синхронизируются через "одно место" и когда запрос обслуживает обновлённый узел, то образ свежий, а когда необновлённый - старый. Удаление тэга (скорее всего) синхронизировалось бы через то же самое "место".  Стоит обновить Nexus для начала, а потом и к разработчикам обратиться. Какие-то проблемы у них в прошлом были, например https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-18186 или https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-25626